# Lua - Calculate watts being used by a light bulb, based on its brightness level?

Tags: math, lua

I was sent the following code as an example of what I could do to calculate the watts being used by a hue light bulb, based on its model number and brightness level..

```
if hue_model == "LWB010" and hue_state == true then
   if hue_level <= 0 then watt = 0.4 end
   if (hue_level > 0 and hue_level <= 6) then watt = 1.6 end
   if (hue_level > 6 and hue_level <= 13) then watt = 1.7 end
   if (hue_level > 13 and hue_level <= 20) then watt = 1.8 end
   if (hue_level > 20 and hue_level <= 26) then watt = 1.9 end
   if (hue_level > 26 and hue_level <= 33) then watt = 2.2 end
   if (hue_level > 33 and hue_level <= 40) then watt = 2.4 end
   if (hue_level > 40 and hue_level <= 46) then watt = 2.7 end
   if (hue_level > 46 and hue_level <= 53) then watt = 3.0 end
   if (hue_level > 53 and hue_level <= 60) then watt = 3.5 end
   if (hue_level > 60 and hue_level <= 66) then watt = 3.9 end
   if (hue_level > 66 and hue_level <= 73) then watt = 4.5 end
   if (hue_level > 73 and hue_level <= 80) then watt = 5.1 end
   if (hue_level > 73 and hue_level <= 86) then watt = 5.5 end
   if (hue_level > 86 and hue_level <= 93) then watt = 6.4 end
   if (hue_level > 93) then watt = 6.7 end
   print(watt)
    else
    print("light is off")
    end
```

As the brightness range returned by the Hue API seems to have changed from 0-100 to 0-255, the above needs to be updated. And as part of that work, I’d like to make it more efficient (less code) and also more precise.

Logic suggests that when the light’s on full (255) it will be using 6.7w, and if it’s at 50% (127), that’ll drop to approx (3.35w)

Sadly after trying various thing, I keep failing badly, and find myself reverting back to something very long like the original look up type table above. Surely there’s a better/cleaner way ?

If so, please could someone share what they would do.

Many thanks..

Comment: Shouldn't 50% result in 3.0? Is there some formula that you haven't told us about?

Comment: I agree, it would be nice to see the source for those numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should check your data.

According to the datasheet a Phillips Hue White LWB010 has a maximum power of 9W.

Cutting your data at 93%, 6.7W doesn't look clever to me in most scenarios.

I checked another source which given the overall presentation I would trust more than your numbers.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Hue/comments/8kvcsi/power_consumption_hue_white_a60_lwb010/

[image]

According to those measurements, you're about 2W off at 93% and as you clamp your values here your 100% wattage is off by almost 4W!

Now to the coding part:

Looking at the plot I'd say an exponential function will give a good approximation.

[image]

```
local wattsFromDim = {
  LWB010 = function (dim) return 0.43981651 * math.exp(0.012712893 * dim) end
}
-- how to use:
local watts = wattsFromDim.LWB010(128)
```

This makes sense as the brightness perception of the human eye is logarithmic.

So in order to provide linear dimming (you'd expect 50% to be half as bright as 100%) the output power must follow logarithms inverse, an exponential function.

Comment: Thanks so much @Piglet and apologies for not being clearer in my original post, my focus was more on seeing if there was a formula that could be used, instead of having to write a long look up table . Also I have a number of different hue bulb models, with different watts - how best can I calculate the formula for each bulb’s different wattage  ?

Comment: you can do it the same way for all lamps. find or measure those values, fit a curve and add it to the function list.

Comment: thanks again, but sadly maths is not my strong point, so I’m struggling to know where to start based on your formula? As I’m initially after a guide,  is it possible/would it be easier to have a fixed exponential growth function, (https://i.imgur.com/pVGhM5y.png) ? Where i submit the dim level (0-255) and the bulb watts (6.4 -10.2) E.g function = brightness2watts (dim_level, watts) ?

Comment: That formula is true for those measurements. its just a exponential function fit. I did it in LibreOffice Calc, There are countless other ways. transferring this from one to another lamp type is probably not going to work for multiple reasons. ideally measure the power dissipation yourself. never trust any datasheet. ask a friend who knows how to safely measure high voltage so you don't kill yourself

Comment: Hi @Piglet, I’d love to give it a go, as I can create the table, showing watts used vs brightness (0-255)  - I just can’t  work out how you did the maths via libreOffice Calc to get that formula -. If I get a table of say 10 measurements, Please could you explain the calculate (step by step)?

Comment: make a xy scatter plot, right click a point, select "add trendline", then pick exponential.  maybe there's faster ways but that was the quickest I could think of. please use websearch for this. search "curve fitting"

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should use Lua math operations to perform this task. However, to make it easier, i've just copied the existing table into a new format.

```lua
local wattTable = {
        [ 1 ] = 1.6 ,
        [ 2 ] = 1.7 ,
        [ 3 ] = 1.8 ,
        [ 4 ] = 1.9 ,
        [ 5 ] = 2.2 ,
        [ 6 ] = 2.4 ,
        [ 7 ] = 2.7 ,
        [ 8 ] = 3.0 ,
        [ 9 ] = 3.5 ,
        [ 10 ] = 3.9 ,
        [ 11 ] = 4.5 ,
        [ 12 ] = 5.1 ,
        [ 13 ] = 5.5 ,
        [ 14 ] = 6.4 ,
}
```

Previously, you used jumps of about 6.5, which translates to about 16.5 on the new scale. We can use `math.floor(hue/16.5)` to get the index for this table.

However, values less than 0 and more than 240 will be out of bounds of the table (the bounds being 1 to 14). So, we can perform some checks:

```lua
local index = math.floor(hue / 16.5)
if index <= 0 then
    return 0.4
elseif index >= 15 then
    return 6.7
```

After that, we can just read from the table:

```
else
    return wattTable[index]
end
```

Here is the completed code:

```lua
local wattTable = {
        [ 1 ] = 1.6 ,
        [ 2 ] = 1.7 ,
        [ 3 ] = 1.8 ,
        [ 4 ] = 1.9 ,
        [ 5 ] = 2.2 ,
        [ 6 ] = 2.4 ,
        [ 7 ] = 2.7 ,
        [ 8 ] = 3.0 ,
        [ 9 ] = 3.5 ,
        [ 10 ] = 3.9 ,
        [ 11 ] = 4.5 ,
        [ 12 ] = 5.1 ,
        [ 13 ] = 5.5 ,
        [ 14 ] = 6.4 ,
}

function getWattage(hue)
    local index = math.floor(hue / 16.5)
    if index <= 0 then
        return 0.4
    elseif index >= 15 then
        return 6.7
    else
        return wattTable[index]
    end
end
```

Here is an example of using it:

```lua
print(getWattage(150))
```

Summary: Using a table and some if conditions, we have created a function which accepts all numbers as valid values (bulletproof), and allows us to adjust the range of hue values from 0-100 (6.5) to 0-255 (16.5).